# Sum of a Series (Calculus )

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Evaluate the following sum as $n\to\infty$:
>   $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k(k+1)}{2x^{k-1}}, \quad|x|>1$$
>   **Source:** Exercise 14, http://www.mathem.pub.ro/_SITE_ELEVI/e-2005-a1.pdf .

Thank you for your patience , I'd be grateful for any idea .

Comment: Answer is A....

Comment: I edited your question to make use of $\LaTeX$.  Please make sure that I didn't mistakenly misrepresent your query. :)

Comment: Amusingly, the issue of values of $ \ x \ $ being _outside_ the radius of convergence of the _infinite_ power series is irrelevant (just a little something to see if the student is paying attention).  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

$$\text{For}\;\;|z|<1\;:\;\;\begin{align*}\frac1{1-z}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k\\{}\\
\frac1{(1-z)^2}&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kz^{k-1}\\{}\\\frac2{(1-z)^3}&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)z^{k-1}\end{align*}$$

Now do some algebraic order in the above and put $\;x:=\frac1z\;$ ...

Comment: Since it's a multiple-choice exam, if you know that each successive derivative of $ \ (1-z)^{-1} \ $ puts another factor involving $ \ k \ $ in the numerator of the power series, _and_ that this is a _finite_ series, you can eliminate everything other than (a) .